# MySQL: Count rows by field

Tags: sql, mysql

All rows in a table have a `type` field which is either 0 or 1.

I need to count rows with 0 and with 1 in one query. So that result should look something like:

```
type0 | type1
------+------
1234  | 4211
```

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
select type, count(type) from tbl_table group by type;
```

Comment: I realize that my query will result in the transpose of the OP's desired output format, but I'm assuming it's OK.

Answer (score 4):

Lessee...

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE type WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type0,
    SUM(CASE type WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type1
FROM
   tableX;
```

This has *not* been tested.

Comment: Do you really need the FROM clause? ... In MySQL that would add an unnecessary table scan.

Comment: Er, yes, you need the FROM clause. That's how you indicate which table you're reading the column `type` from.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [subqueries as scalar operands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/scalar-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE type = 0) AS type0,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE type = 1) AS type1;
```

Tested in MySQL as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, type INT);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL, 0);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL, 0);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL, 1);

SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t WHERE type = 0) AS type0,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t WHERE type = 1) AS type1;

+-------+-------+
| type0 | type1 |
+-------+-------+
|     2 |     3 | 
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Daniel - won't that have to scan the table twice (e.g. see comment on the page you linked to)?

Comment: @martin: Yes it does. The accepted answer would be the most efficient. Apparently I gave too much importance to the OP's suggested output.

Answer (score 1):

A result like this can easily be achieved:

```
Type  Count
-----------
type0 1234
type1 4221
```

You can use something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT('type', [type]) as Type, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Type
```

Comment: Note that in MySQL, the `+` is not a concatenation operator.